# call binary from docker container inside another docker container?

Tags: docker, best-practices, containers, binary

What would be the way to load a certain binary from a certain container in docker from inside another container?

container 1: web
container 2: ffmpeg

I would want to call ffmpeg binary living in container 2 from the container 1.
Confused on how to process this

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it straight forward.

You can do one of the following:

- Make your web container communicate with ffmpeg container using RPC/agent.
- Use queue service, so your ffmpeg container listen to the queue job.
- Run [docker inside docker](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/).